# Getting "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" trying NODE.JS authentication with KeyCloak

Tags: node.js, npm, keycloak

I'm using Node.JS (express) and an NPM called [keycloak-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect) to connect to a keycloak server.
When I'm implementing the default mechanism as described to protect a route:

```
app.get( '/about', keycloak.protect(), function(req,resp) {
    resp.send( 'Page: ' + req.params.page + '<br><a href="/logout">logout</a>');
} );
```

I do get referred to keycloak, but with following error: "**Invalid parameter: redirect_uri**"

**My query string is:** (xx for demonstration)
 `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=account&state=aa11b27a-8a0b-4a3b-89dc-cb8a303dbde8&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3002%2Fabout%3Fauth_callback%3D1&response_type=code`

**My keycloak.json is:** (xx for demonstration)

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "realm-public-key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwS00kUaH6OoERNSkFUwxEBxx2SsqmHu9oVQiPs6nlP9fNQm0cK2lpNPphbLzooZL6kivaC4VzXg20F3zY7jRDc4U/XHgXjZVZUXxJ0NeCI5ESDo00EV9xh9XL3xvXslmG0YLWpywtQSYc+XcGDkz87edokbHQIIlQc2sgoVKIKpajZyrI5wnyMhL8JSk+Mdo2T9DeNnZxPkauiKBwWFJReBO51gsoZ49cbD39FRa8pLi8W0TtXoESIf/eGUSdc3revVFR7cjzHUzxF0p0WrLsTA1aBCLkt8yhnq88NqcKsW5mkxRmhLdw20ODTdsmRtm68rjtusMwifo/dZLJ9v5eQIDAQAB",
  "auth-server-url": "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "account",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "9140d4e6-ed05-4899-a3c0-a9cf94ab407d"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true
}
```

**keycloak configuration:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you added a port to your client URLs in your client settings tab.

e.g.

```
root url: https://demo.server.biz:443/cxf
```

just remove the port

```
root url: https://demo.server.biz/cxf
```

the same goes for `Valid Redirect URIs` and `Web Origins`

## 1 Update

[image]

## 2 Update with your url

[image]

Comment: I had no ports, just the defaults values, I'll update my question to contain a screenshot from keycloak. I've also try to add "localhost" to these fields

Comment: Is http://localhost the url you tried to secure? If not add the URL you try to secure. I extended my answer with screenshot, too.

Comment: In this case you either have to add `/about` or you need a wildcard (*). See attached screenshot.

Comment: thanks, I've also tried the wildcard before and I get the same result

Comment: I'm just curious did you apply the configuration like I did in my second example? Are you using cxf or resteasy?

Comment: I'll try the second example. Anyhow I'm now sure the caveat is something on the keycloak side rather than Node.JS, which is an acceptable answer for me in the meanwhile, so thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Solve my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you will continue with the doubt but I had to configure the node server with https calls in the following way:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
.....
const HOST = 'your_site.com';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const key = fs.readFileSync('./certs/private.pem');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('./certs/public.pem');
const https_options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert
};
var serverKeycloak = https.createServer(https_options, appKeyCloak);
serverKeycloak.listen(PORT, HOST);
...
```

then the adapter automatically send to keycloak the https