# Keycloak invalid redirect_uri error with Angular

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I am using Keycloak authentication to authenticate an angular app and so far I have managed to redirect my login to keycloak server.  But when redirected instead of the login page I am getting a 500 error page with the message **Invalid parameter: redirect_uri**.
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115626/getting-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri-trying-node-js-authentication-with-key) stackoverflow answer and made sure that my client settings are correct. But no matter what I changed it to I get the same log message on keycloak console.

**Keycloak log**

> 09:39:21,369 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-62) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=camunda-demo-auth, clientId=camunda-demo-client, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=http://localhost:9002/

**My Client Settings**
**Update** [Changed settings according to RobbyCornelissen's suggestions]

[image]

**Angular Login Redirection**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  window._keycloak = Keycloak('../src/app/resources/keycloak.json');

  window._keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'})
    .success(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['adfWidgetSample']); // manually bootstrap Angular
    });
});
```

Comment: Client settings are incorrect. Your "Valid redirect URIs" setting does not match your actual redirect URI.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Could please explain?

Comment: Your redirect URI is `http://localhost:9002/`. The one in your settings is `http://localhost:9002/dashboard`. So they're not the same.

Comment: I changed it to `http://localhost:9002/`. But still I am getting the same error

Comment: try with `http://localhost:9002/*`