# Keycloak login page shows 'invalid parameter: redirect_uri'

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am using Keycloak authentication to authenticate an angular app and so far I have managed to redirect my login to Keycloak server. But when redirected instead of the login page I am getting a 500 error page with the message `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`

Comment: So what have you put as redirect url in the client configuration screen of the keycloak console ?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115626/getting-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri-trying-node-js-authentication-with-key/37117339#37117339

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect\_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352880/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri)

Answer (score 13):

When you created the client in Keycloak you set the required 'Valid Redirect URIs' field. Most likely the pattern you entered there doesn't match the redirect uri you are sending from your client. If you use ports numbers, they have to match too!.
If this is not the problem, check what your Keycloak server is logging and add those details here to your question.

Answer (score 3):

this is occurred due to base url and valid redirect url are different. So I have added same URL on both the text box.Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error while logging out then you need to enter the following command while starting the keycloak server

```
bin/kc.sh --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true start-dev --http-port 8180
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional possibility for this error: Incorrect ClientID.

I had copy pasted (I know..) my settings and forgotten to alter the client id. So it was pointing to a Client that actually did not exist on my Realm, this will cause 'invalid parameter: redirect_uri' as well apperently.